# How can we compare a variable having many values with a value which is we are going to parameterize in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How can we compare a variable having many values with a value which is we are going to parameterize

Consider

Variable name : Project

While correlation we are capturing all the projects in a page using -1

It captures all the names of cities like Project1:* Project2:* Project3:* ProjectN:*

No of Project may change every time

New Project:"Project1"

How can we write code as that the new project is present in Project variables and I need to get the matched project name and its respective code

From the below response I'm getting the project code

/isc_RPCResponseStart-->[{affectedRows:0,data:[{dotprojectseqnum:1,brandName:"Curries",companyId:166,newOrExisting:"Imported",**projectCode:"CuLoTestFR3"**,projectDesc:"AMBER POCASSET HIGH SCHOOL",framePoNumber:"7426",lastchange:new Date(1660918747253),masterProject:"Not Assigned to Any",**projectId:149205**,rowID:1},{brandName:"Curries",ppof:"Y",newOrExisting:"New",rowID:2,dotprojectseqnum:0,companyId:166,projectCode:"ppof28",imported:"N",projectDesc:"jkj",lastchange:new Date(1640697895847),masterProject:"Not Assigned to Any",projectId:144412,selected:0},{brandName:"Curries",ppof:"Y",newOrExisting:"New",rowID:3,dotprojectseqnum:0,companyId:166,projectCode:"12272021",imported:"N",projectDesc:"PPOF ",lastchange:new Date(1640659904817),masterProject:"Not Assigned to Any",projectId:144385,selected:0},{brandName:"Curries",ppof:"Y",newOrExisting:"New",rowID:4,dotprojectseqnum:0,companyId:166,projectCode:"2-10-21",imported:"N",projectDesc:"PPOF",lastchange:new Date(1613013416263),masterProject:"Not Assigned to Any",projectId:130500,selected:0}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether `Project1` value is present in "all the projects" you can use the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code in the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor):

```
vars.entrySet().findAll {var -> var.getKey().matches('Project_(\\d+)')}.collect{var -> var.getValue()}.contains('Project1')
```

Where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, check out JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

Comment: Thanks @ Dmitri . Can you tell me How to verify the result? because i dont get any result in the console for the above script. And also how can i get the matched project name's id

Comment: If `Project1` is present in `Project_1`, `Project_2` etc variables - it will return `true`, otherwise `false`. I have no idea how to get "matched project name's id because there is no any IDs in your question

Comment: I have attached the response image in the query. In that I'm capturing all the 'project codes' and matching with the string value which is parameterized.  Now my query here is when the project code and the parameterized value is equal then i need to get the relevant 'project id' which is also highlighted in the response

Comment: [Don't post code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Interesting, you're asking for help and at the same time refusing to provide the necessary information and trying to argue. Please familiarize yourself with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).